# What does "==>" mean in coq?

Tags: coq

I have the following code:
Here is the def of sorted:

```
Fixpoint sorted (l : list nat) := 
  match l with 
  | [] => true 
  | x::xs => match xs with 
             | [] => true 
             | y :: ys => (x <=? y) && (sorted xs) 
             end 
  end.
```

Here is the def of insert:

```
Fixpoint insert (x : nat) (l : list nat) := 
  match l with 
  | [] => [x] 
  | y::ys => if x <=? y then x :: l 
             else y :: insert x ys 
  end.
```

Here is the def of insert_spec:

```
Definition insert_spec (x : nat) (l : list nat) :=
  sorted l ==> sorted (insert x l).
```

In insert_spec, what does "==>" mean?

Comment: It's not a standard notation. It'll help to know where you got this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you got the code from Software Foundations' [QuickChick guide](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/qc-current/QC.html). Many (if not all) of the notations used in that guide can be found in the [QuickChick Reference Manual](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/qc-current/QuickChickInterface.html). There, we find that `"==>"` is defined as a notation.

```
Module QcNotation.
  Export QcDefaultNotation.
  Notation "x ==> y" :=
    (implication x y) (at level 55, right associativity)
    : Checker_scope.
End QcNotation.
```

`implication` is a generic "is this implication true" parameter used by QuickChick.

```
Parameter implication :
  ∀ {prop : Type} `{Checkable prop} (b : bool) (p : prop), Checker.
```

Whenever the first argument is true, QuickChick tests that the second argument evaluates (in whatever context you're using QuickChick in) as true too.

So for your particular piece of code, `"==>"` is used to say that we want to test that whenever `l` is sorted, `insert x l` is sorted too.